# Finding image in RSS feed - iOS

Tags: ios, image, rss

I am making an app for my site, which I need to include images in the table view.

RSS picture I'm trying to find:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img width="1100" height="1010" src="http://www.x86cam.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/twilight_sparkle_with_the_twicane_by_diamondsword11-d6vn28u.png" class="attachment- wp-post-image" alt="twilight_sparkle_with_the_twicane_by_diamondsword11-d6vn28u" style="display: none" />I will not give any links, but I just need to warn y&#8217;all. Watch out for spoilers all over sites. Source: Here
]]>
</description>
```

I don't know how I would find the image tag in this.

```
#pragma mark - parsing of RssFeed Values

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        desc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        image = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        pubDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:desc forKey:@"description"];
        [item setObject:pubDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        [link appendString:string];
    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"]){
        [desc appendString:string];
    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]){
        [pubDate appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I would like the app to parse the XML and find the `<img>` tag in the `<description>` and then get the `src=""`

Anyone willing and able to help me on this?

Comment: Have you verified that your code to parse the XML is extracting the desired data such as the image URL?

Comment: My code is not finding the <img src=""> tag at all.

Comment: Then you should redo your question to focus on the problem with parsing the XML data. Until that is solved there is no point in worrying about the table view.

Comment: You need to post your code related to parsing the XML. Get rid of the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Point out the problem you are having with your XML parsing code.

Comment: Fixed code and deleted `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42228/discussion-between-x86cam-and-rmaddy)

Answer (score 0):

The image link your are looking to extract is inside a CDATA block, but rss parser ignores CDATA block.

If you need to extract the string from CDATA, you could use this block in foundCDATA:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{

NSMutableString *cdstring = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

now the mutablestring "cdstring" will be containing:

"img width="1100" height="1010" src="http://www.x86cam.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/twilight_sparkle_with_the_twicane_by_diamondsword11-d6vn28u.png" class="attachment- wp-post-image" alt="twilight_sparkle_with_the_twicane_by_diamondsword11-d6vn28u" style="display: none" />I will not give any links, but I just need to warn y’all. Watch out for spoilers all over sites. Source: Here"

now just search for src=" using stringcontainsstring and extract the link

-cheers :)
P.S: if you can ask the provider of rss feed to give it in normal block without CDATA, you can extract the link easily by using following method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:  (NSDictionary *)attributeDict

// In this method parameter 'attributeDict' will return you all the sub attributes of main attribute.
// In your case its 'url' of Picture.

// I hope this will help you. Check this out.
if ([element isEqualToString:@"img"]){
[attributeDict valueForKey:<@"src">]
}
```

Hope it helps